# Need help in subproblem of parser for polynomials (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm currently doing an assignment for college where we are implementing an polynomial calculator in Haskell.
The first part of the assignment is doing poly operations, and that is already done.
We get extra credit if we implement an parser for the polynomial, which I'm currently doing by turning a string to a tuple of [(factor, [(variable, exponent)])].

This means **"-10y^4 - 5z^5" => "[(-10, [('y', 4)]), (-5, [('z', 5)]**.
The sub-problem I'm having trouble with is when I encounter polynomials like **"5xy^2z^3"** that should be stored as **[(5, [('x',1), ('y', 2),('z',3)]]**, I don't know how to parse it.

Any suggestion on how I could approach this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
-- Slipts lists by chosen Char, only used with '+' in this project
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split _ "" = []
split c s = firstWord : (split c rest)
    where firstWord = takeWhile (/=c) s
          rest = drop (length firstWord + 1) s

-- Remove all spaces from a string, for easier parsing
formatSpace :: String -> String
formatSpace = filter (not . isSpace)

-- Clever way to parse the polynomial, add an extra '+' before every '-'
-- so after we split the string by '+', it helps us keep the '-'
simplify_minus :: String -> String
simplify_minus [] = ""
simplify_minus (x:xs)
        | x == '^' = x : head xs : simplify_minus (tail xs)
        | x == '-' = "+-" ++ simplify_minus xs
        | otherwise =  x : simplify_minus xs

-- Splits an String by occurrences of '+' and creates a list of those sub-strings
remove_plus :: String -> [String]
remove_plus s =  split '+' s

-- Removes multiplication on substrings
remove_mult :: [String] -> [[String]]
remove_mult [] = []
remove_mult (x:xs) =  (remove_power (split '*' x)) : remove_mult xs

-- Function used to separate a variable that has an power. This translates ["y^2] to [["y", "2"]] 
remove_power :: [String] -> [String]
remove_power  [] = []
remove_power (x:xs) = (split '^' x) ++ remove_power xs

-- Wrapper function for all the functions necessary to the parser
parse_poly :: String -> [(Integer, String, Integer)]
parse_poly [] = []
parse_poly s = map (tuplify) (rem_m (remove_plus (simplify_minus (formatSpace s))))

rem_m :: [String] -> [String]
rem_m l = map (filter (not . (=='*'))) l 

helper_int :: String -> Integer
helper_int s 
    | s == "" = 1
    | s == "-" = -1
    | otherwise = read s :: Integer

helper_char :: String -> String
helper_char s
    | s == [] = " "
    | otherwise = s

tuplify :: String -> (Integer, String, Integer)
tuplify l = (helper_int t1, helper_char t3, helper_int (drop 1 t4))
    where (t1, t2)  = (break (isAlpha) l)
          (t3, t4) = (break (=='^') t2)

main :: IO() 
main = do
    putStr("\nRANDOM TESTING ON THE WAE\n")
    
    putStr("--------------\n")

    print(parse_poly "5*xyz^3 - 10*y^4 - 5*z^5 - x^2 - 5 - x")
    -- [(5,"xyz",3),(-10,"y",4),(-5,"z",5),(-1,"x",2),(-5," ",1),(-1,"x",1)]

``
```

Comment: Can you please show the current state of your parser?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it into the post, it was too large for a comment

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much everything there already, but you do need to use `break` recursively to grab everything until the next variable. You probably should also use the similar `span` to first grab the coefficient.

```
parsePositiveMonomial :: String -> (Integer, [(Char, Integer)])
parsePositiveMonomial s = case span isDigit s of
        ([], varPows) -> (1, parseUnitMonomial varPows)
        (coef, varPows) -> (read coef, parseUnitMonomial varPows)
 where parseUnitMonomial [] = []
       parseUnitMonomial (var:s') = case break isAlpha s' of
          ...
```